# TypeScript error tells me "Property 'fluid' does not exist on type 'GatsbyImage'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, gatsby, gatsby-image

In Gatsby, I have used a page query to retrieve some data:

```
allContentfulArtwork(sort: { fields: [artistName], order: ASC }) {
  edges {
    node {
      image {
        fluid(resizingBehavior: SCALE) {
          ...GatsbyContentfulFluid
        }
      }
      altTag
      title
      artistName
      countryOfOrigin
      contentful_id
    }
  }
}
```

I save the result of this query in a variable called `artworkData`. I have a React component that accepts this data in props to render it to the page (props unrelated to this question are marked with * and can be ignored):

```
{artworkData.edges.map((artwork) => {
  return (
    <Artwork
      *alreadyVoted={alreadyVoted}
      altTag={artwork.node.altTag}
      artistName={artwork.node.artistName}
      contentful_id={artwork.node.contentful_id}
      countryOfOrigin={artwork.node.countryOfOrigin}
      *hasVoted={hasVoted}
      image={artwork.node.image}
      key={artwork.node.contentful_id}
      *location={location}
      title={artwork.node.title}
      ></Artwork>
  );
})}
```

I have defined the shape of `Artwork` component's props in the following TypeScript interface:

```
interface ArtworkProps {
  alreadyVoted(): void;
  altTag: string;
  artistName: string;
  contentful_id: string;
  countryOfOrigin: string;
  hasVoted: boolean;
  image: GatsbyImage;
  location: GatsbyRouteComponentProps;
  title: string;
}
```

I destructure my props and use them in the component (styled component definitions ommitted for brevity):

```
const Artwork: React.FC<ArtworkProps> = ({ alreadyVoted, altTag, artistName, contentful_id, countryOfOrigin, hasVoted, image, location, title }) => {
  return (
    <ArtworkWrapper>
      <Img fluid={image.fluid} alt={altTag ? altTag : title}></Img>
    < /ArtworkWrapper>

    // a bunch of additional render code
  )
}
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript says `"Property 'fluid' does not exist on type 'GatsbyImage'.ts(2339)"`

Well, I think it does, because an `Img` component in Gatsby has a `fluid` property that you use to pass the fluid data for rendering. As far as I can see from looking through [the `index.d.ts` file in Gatsby Image](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-image/index.d.ts), this property does exist. If we follow the heirarchy, the class `GatsbyImage` contains the type `GatsbyImageProps`, which can be either `GatsbyImageFluidProps` interface or `GatsbyImageFixedProps` interface; `GatsbyImageFluidProps` has the fluid property defined.

I am using gatsby 2.26.1, gatsby-image 2.5.0, TypeScript 4.0.5. Warning showing in VSCode 1.51.1.

Comment: Is the rest of the query fetching the data properly?

Comment: @FerranBuireu Indeed, the data is coming in correctly across the board. I can see the image itself, it's just the typing that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You seem like importing `GatsbyImage` class whose incoming prop is `GatsbyImageProps` and `GatsbyImage` class does not export anything other than itself.

You want to import `GatsbyImageProps` https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-image/index.d.ts#L65 instead and assign it to your `Artwork` component's props type.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I change the type in my interface of `image` to `GatsbyImageProps`?

I tried this and unfortunately it made no difference. In fact, the error remains the same - `Property 'fluid' does not exist on type 'GatsbyImage'`. I think therefore that TS is overriding my declaration with its inference in some way? If I am excplicitly stating it is of type `GatsbyImageProps`, how can it continue to give me errors related to `GatsbyImage`?